# how to adjust canvas filter blur depending on device size

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, rendering, blur

I am trying to apply a blur to a canvas and I am trying to apply it with the same strength on every device.

```js
    // this.#blur is usually 7
    const ctx = this.#canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.filter = "blur(" + this.#blur + "px)";
    const draw_2DCanvas = () => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(this.#video, width_diff, height_diff, width, height);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw_2DCanvas);
    };
    draw_2DCanvas();
```

But with just this the blur strength changes depending on the device, possibly because the canvas size differs.
The blur applies as intended on pc devices, but is too strong on mobile devices.
So I tried to spice things a little and change the blur in accordance to the current canvas style width (the canvas and video size is 360x270 but the html style size is responsive).

```js
    // this.#blur is usually 7
    const ctx = this.#canvas.getContext("2d");
    const draw_2DCanvas = () => {
        const blur =  Math.ceil(this.#blur * this.#canvas.clientWidth / 360);
        ctx.filter = "blur(" + blur + "px)";
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(this.#video, width_diff, height_diff, width, height);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw_2DCanvas);
    };
    draw_2DCanvas();
```

But this time the blur is too strong on pc devices and a little too weak on mobile devices.
What is the correct way to make the canvas blur consistent on every device?

Comment: maybe look at devicePixelRatio https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! But it seems to still have some issues, I will post an answer after I fix them

Comment: fixed 'em issues! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final code to fix the blur before I explain the how or why:

```js
    import "context-filter-polyfill/dist/index.js";
    const resize_dvr = this.#device.os == 'iOS' ? 1 : window.devicePixelRatio;
    const width = calc_width / resize_dvr;
    const height = calc_height / resize_dvr;
    const width_diff = this.#ar ? calc_wdiff / resize_dvr / 2 : 0;
    const height_diff = this.#ar ? calc_hdiff / resize_dvr / 2 : 0;
    const ctx = this.#canvas.getContext("2d");
    //do not use window.devicePixelRatio to calculate width here
    this.#canvas.width = calc_width;
    this.#canvas.height = calc_height;
    ctx.scale(resize_dvr, resize_dvr);
    ctx.filter = "blur(" + this.#blur + "px)";
    const draw_2DCanvas = () => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(this.#video, width_diff, height_diff, width, height);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw_2DCanvas);
    };
    draw_2DCanvas();
```

I'll start by saying that something like `blur = blur * window.devicePixelRatio` will not blur properly!
Also this is a simplified version of my code to make it more readable so is hasn't been tested as is.
After testing directly changing the blur I tried changing the value of the scale like this:
(as shown in protob's link)

```js
ctx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
```

This managed to fix the blur for Android devices, but made the blur waaay too strong in iOS devices and also made Android devices zoom like crazy.
To fix the Android device version I simply divided all the canvas coordinates by window.devicePixelRatio like this:

```js
    const resize_dvr = window.devicePixelRatio;
    const width = calc_width / resize_dvr;
    const height = calc_height / resize_dvr;
    const width_diff = this.#ar ? calc_wdiff / resize_dvr / 2 : 0;
    const height_diff = this.#ar ? calc_hdiff / resize_dvr / 2 : 0;
```

However iOS devices do not support `ctx.filter` at all! (more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter#browser_compatibility))
So I was fully relying on the `context-filter-polyfill` for IOS devices, and this library seems to fully monkey patch the code with a `window.devicePixelRatio = 1` setting.
So I had to change the devicePixelRatio i got to 1 for devices that had to rely on this library.

```
    const resize_dvr = this.#device.os == 'iOS' ? 1 : window.devicePixelRatio;
```

Here is how you can catch an IOS device with your code:

```
const isIOS = /iP(hone|([oa])d)|Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent) && 'ontouchend' in document;
```

I do not recommend using libraries when catching IOS devices cuz they just read the userAgent as is, and iPads always fake being a Mac OS! (while having none of the web API you can use on a Mac available....)
And if you do use a library remember to double check that it catches all IOS devices!